# Would Azure Active Directory be appropriate for a internet application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I know Azure AD would probably be pretty good for crediting a enterprise-class application, i.e. something used inside a corp. However what about if I am creating a public facing internet application. I need typical identity components, sign-in, sign-out, etc. Let's just say 10,000 users. Would azure AD be good for this?

Comment: You have Active Directory in mind, which is an on-premises identity solution. Azure Active Directory is on the cloud, so yes it would help with your case (see [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code)). You might also want to check Azure AD B2C.

Comment: The answer is 'Yes', why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think azure ad b2c will meet the demand.It provides business-to-customer identity as a service. Your customers use their preferred social, enterprise, or local account identities to get single sign-on access to your applications and APIs.You can customize the entire user experience with your brand.Azure AD B2C uses standards-based authentication protocols including OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0, and SAML. It integrates with most modern applications and commercial off-the-shelf software etc.You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview).